# DynamoDB Scan FilterExpression returning empty result

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to filter the data returned by a dynamodb scan operation using nodejs aws sdk but the data returned has 0 items.

`Response : {"Items":[],"Count":0,"ScannedCount":15}`

I have tried with both FilterExpression and ScanFilter but getting the same result.

FilterExpression:

```
var params = {
            TableName: tableName,
            FilterExpression: 'active = :active',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':active': {
                    S: '1'
                }
            }
        };
```

ScanFilter:

```
var params = {
            TableName: tableName,
            ScanFilter: {
                'active': {
                    "AttributeValueList": [{ "S": "1" }],
                    "ComparisonOperator": "EQ"
                }
            }
        };
```

Here is the nodejs code:

```
        dynamodb.scan(params, onScan);

        function onScan(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:', JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != 'undefined') {
                    params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                    dynamodb.scan(params, onScan);
                }
                if (data && data.Items)
                    callback(data.Items);
                else
                    callback(null);
            }
        }
```

I checked the same filter condition in the dynamodb console and getting the expected result.

[dynamodb console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGbR.png)

Comment: Is your code getting into the `LastEvaluatedKey != 'undefined'` condition? In other words are you dealing with more than one call to `dynamodb.scan()`? What is the code for the `callback()` function? This isn't running in a Lambda function is it?

Comment: @MarkB No, the code is not dealing with more than one call to dynamodb.scan() and the callback is a node express application running on an EC2 instance.

Comment: can you try `ExpressionAttributeValues : {':active': '1'}` in the FilterExpressions

Answer (score 11):

@bharathp answer did the trick for me,

in aws command line had to specify the parameter as **{"S":"s1"}**

```
aws dynamodb scan \
 --table-name aws-nodejs-typescript-dev \
 --filter-expression "id = :search" \
 --expression-attribute-values '{":search":{"S":"s1"}}'
```

in node code just **":search": "s1"**

```
const params = {
  TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":search": "s1"
  },
  FilterExpression: "id = :search",
  ProjectionExpression: "id",
};

dynamoDb.scan(params, (error, result) => {
```

Comment: literally been at this for hours, thank you for clearing up the issue (in this case of insanely fragmented AWS command formatting requirements)

Comment: You totally saved me. Was wandering why it's cannot be found in the official docs though?

Comment: You got to be be kidding me...
It looks like there's the very same situation with the Python's Boto3 SDK.
Seems that [official docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan) contain an error (correct me if I'm missing sth).
Even the example use of the method is wrong then..
You guys just saved me god knows how much hours of troubleshooting. Many thx!

Answer (score 3):

This was working just fine for me on AWS CLI,

aws dynamodb scan \

> ```
>  --table-name myTableName \
>  --filter-expression "email = :a" \
>  --expression-attribute-values '{":a":{"S":"xxxxx@xxxxx.com"}}'
> ```

However when trying to write the same query on NodeJs/Angular5/typescript it fails:

```
private getDynamoEmail(email: string): Promise<ScanOutput> {
    const params: any = {
     TableName: this.config.database.myTableHere,
     KeyConditionExpression "email = :e" 
     ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":email": {
        S: email, // Had to remove this part to work and use 
                  // ExpressionAttributeNames instead
       },
     },
     FilterExpression: ":e = :email",
    };
    return this.docClient.scan(params).promise();
}
```

In order to work I had to omit the attribute type so here is the code working:

```
private getDynamoEmail(email: string): Promise<ScanOutput> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    const params: any = {
     ExpressionAttributeNames: {"#email": "email"},
     ExpressionAttributeValues: {":email": email},
     FilterExpression: "#email = :email",
     TableName: this.config.database.registeredLiveAccounts,
    };
    return this.docClient.scan(params).promise();
}
```

Hope helps
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that 15 items are scanned and no items found. You might find the item in your loop of:

```
if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != 'undefined') {
  params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
  dynamodb.scan(params, onScan);
}
```

As scan operation scans all the items and filters the match.